# How can I retrieve an entity by key without using filter with JayData

Tags: odata, jaydata

JayData has a method on EntitySet called `find(keyValue, cb)`. However, this method translates to the following OData query:

```
http://localhost/api/MyEntitySet?$filter=(Id eq 1)&$top=2
```

Why doesn't the OData provider query by key instead? Like so:

```
http://localhost/api/MyEntitySet(1)
```

I find the second query to be more natural in this case, also easier to debug. Is there a way to force JayData to use the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, we don't support this now. You can add it to our backlog (http://jaydata.org/backlogs) or open an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks. I found a similar issue already reported, so I added my comment to it: https://github.com/jaydata/jaydata/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

Now it seems to be supported, but not documented yet. I have tested wit the Version 1.3.6. The reuest was translated into

```
http://localhost/api/MyEntitySet(1)
```

The only documentation i found was here (Search for "New find() for OData provider"):

```
http://jaydata.org/blog/release-notes
```